# Is it possbile to take text (inner HTML) and make it into JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to design a website that is called something like "JavaScript Code Drills" where users get prompts of coding interview-like problems and can write solutions which get tested for validity. This is will all be done on the frontend. So I somehow need to go from something like

```
<script>
var f; 
</script>
<div class="prompt">
   <p>Write the body of a function whose one parameter is an array and returns the maximum element of the array (If the array is empty, return undefined).</p>
</div>
<div class="solution">
    function ( arr )
    {
       var max = arr.length > 0 ? arr[0] : undefined;
       for ( var i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i ) if ( arr[i] > max ) max = arr[i];
       return max;
    }
</div>
```

and from that, somehow getting the variable `f` to equal the contents of `#solution` as JS code. Is this type of transformation possible?

Comment: use the eval function onkeypress (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)

Comment: @www139 this question was a trap.  You can now be quoted as saying "use the eval function".  This is your soundbyte.

Comment: @sqykly What is so bad about the `eval()` function? I've actually never used it before but I had heard of it and thought it would be the perfect solution to this question.

Comment: @sqykly Are you referring to this article (http://www.sitepoint.com/call-javascript-function-string-without-using-eval/)?

Comment: Search "eval considered harmful"

Comment: @www139 oh and it is definitely the simplest solution to this problem.  As long as op isn't using it in some way that's a security risk it's the right answer.

Comment: @sqykly I could see how it could be a security concern. If the OP considers it a risk for whatever he's doing with it, he can implement functions to remove harmful script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? I will improve if it doesn't work for you :)

I changed the HTML for simplicity. Please see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp for more information about the `eval()` function.

```js
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
  var f = document.getElementById('solution').innerHTML;
  eval(f);
});
```

```html
<div class="prompt">
  <p>Write the body of a function whose one parameter is an array and returns the maximum element of the array (If the array is empty, return undefined).</p>
</div>
<div id="solution">
  alert('testing');
</div>
```